# Accessibility issue with Select elements

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, accessibility

I'm working on a accessibility issue that the app has with voice over on select elements. Basically, there is a hidden select and a pseudo element with custom styles that acts like a dropdown. This creates a problem when voice over is on because it goes through both of them even though the pseudo element has aria-hidden. Is there any advice on how to make only one select element visible to screen readers?

Please let me know if a code snipped will help explain.

Comment: code snippet always helps

Comment: codesnippet helps, and what screenreader/browser are you using to test this?

Comment: @Skerrvy, the poster already said they're using voiceover, although they didn't say if it was for iOS or OSX, and they didn't specify which browser.  Definitely +1 on the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `aria-hidden` html attribute.

```
<select id="mySelect" aria-hidden="true">...</select>
```

See: http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-hidden

Comment: The original question said they were setting `aria-hidden` already.